# c# int to binary(string) to array

Tags: c#, arrays

I  am learning c# and I want to find out whether the 3rd bit in an integer is a 1 or 0.

So how I am approaching this is to convert the int to a binary. 
Then convert the string to an array.
convert the array of string to an array of ints and slice on the 3rd bit and check  value.

I cannot quite get this to happen. This is where I am at. I am using this example from SO to [convert to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202854/461887)

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Expression
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int number = 3;
        string binValue = Convert.ToString(number, 2);

        char[] array = binValue.ToCharArray();
        array<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            list.add(value);
        }

        int[] binArr = list.ToArray();
        binArr[2] == 1? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a far easier way to do this: by using a bit mask. Check here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261451/using-a-bitmask-in-c-sharp. Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479981/how-do-i-check-if-bitmask-contains-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's entirely the wrong way to do it; just perform binary arithmetic:

```
bool bit3IsSet = (number & 4) != 0;
```

where the `4` is bit 3; you could also use:

```
int bitNumber = 3; // etc
bool bitIsSet = (number & (1 << (bitNumber-1))) != 0;
```

in the general-case.

Comment: That's much easier. Oh well I learnt a lot going the wrong way anyway.

Comment: I am getting True for any number value. using System;
using System.Text;

class Expression
{
 static void Main()
 {
  int number = 100;
  string binValue = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
  System.Console.WriteLine(binValue);
  bool bit3IsSet = (number & 4) != 0;
  System.Console.WriteLine(bit3IsSet);
 }
} #Output C:\Users\Sayth\Documents\Scripts>Expression
1100100
True

Comment: @sayth and bit 3 is set for 100 ;p Try 96 or 104

Comment: I was counting the wrong way left to  right  not right  too left.

Comment: @sayth ah, I see; traditionally, you usually count bit numbers right to left, i.e. starting with the LSB. You can do it the other way, but it will be harder; first you'd need to find the highest set bit, etc.

Comment: Incidentally, the [current plan](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status) is for Roslyn to support binary literals.  This would allow you to replace `bool bit3IsSet = (number & 4) != 0;` with `bool bit3IsSet = (number & 0b00000100) != 0;`.  Whether that is actually more readable depends on how it's being used.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an array conversion: use `String.Substring()` Function (re: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ) to check the value of third bit (in your case: `binValue.Substring(2,1)`; in a short form it could be written like the following:

```
bool _bit3 = (Convert.ToString(number, 2).Substring(2,1)=="1")? true:false;
```